# Elasticsearch bool filter with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

1. I am trying to write a query which will match multiple names, The
   below query is fine but it doesn't exact match for e.g it also gives
   results with the name 'X A' or 'B Y' where I want the name to be
   exact A or exact B.Can anyone tell me what m I doing wrong.
2. Also is it possible to match multiple fields like Name=A or Surname=A or Name=b or Surname=b

   ```
    {
       "filter": {
                   "bool": {
                     "should": [
                       {
                         "term": {
                           "Name": "A"
                         }
                       },{
                         "term": {
                           "Name": "B"
                         }
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 },"sort": [
                   {
                     "Pub": {
                       "Rank": "desc"
                     }
                   }
                 ]
               }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In a boolean query, `must` means all the queries must evaluate true (so is like a logical AND), and `should` means at least one must evaluate true (so is like a logical OR).

1. To have an exact match on the name, you need to use a [Keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html). This will stop the names being tokenized on whitespace, so "William RIker" will be indexed as (Keyword Analyzer) ["William Riker"] or (Default Analyzer) ["William", "Riker"]. In the default case, it would match a term query of either "William" or "Riker". In the keyword case it would only match the full name.
2. To do what you want, "Name=A or Surname=A or Name=b or Surname=b" then you could make 4 should clauses.

```
    {  
       "bool":{  
          "should":[  
             {  
                "term":{  
                   "Name":"A"
                }
             },
             {  
                "term":{  
                   "Name":"B"
                }
             },
             {  
                "term":{  
                   "Surname":"A"
                }
             },
             {  
                "term":{  
                   "Surname":"B"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the query with `must ` but no luck still it still matches  "William" or "Riker"

Comment: My answer to your question part 1 explains why.

Comment: How do I update mapping of Name and make it not_analyzed on the current index ?

Comment: Mappings can't be changed once done, you can only change them when you call create index.

Comment: So in my case it will be Name will not_analyzed right?

Comment: Yes, or set it to use KeywordAnalzyer

Comment: I have changed the mappings to `"Name": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }` is it right ?